# How to prevent the screen off during the call?

Tags: android, screen, phone-call

I am making my own LockScreen using Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON. I want to stop my app when i have a phone call but i can't find the way to do this. the last choice is prevent the screen off during the call. How can i do this? please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of the details of your implementation, but you need to take a look at the [`TelephonyManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html), if you only need to check the state at a certain point in time, you can use the [`getCallState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getCallState%28%29) method.  Otherwise, you can use the [`listen`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen%28android.telephony.PhoneStateListener,%20int%29) method to register a [`PhoneStateListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) to track state changes and have your app respond as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code, it worked:

```
 TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    tm.listen(mPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);


private PhoneStateListener mPhoneListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

                finish();
                break;


            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
               finish();

                break;

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:


                break;

            }
        } 
    };
```

in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```